# Last element of an multidimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional matrix and want to set the last element to 1.(e.g. `w[1,1,1,1,1]= 1)` The dimension varies, so thats my problem. `po[-1]=1` doesn't work here.

Comment: Is this NumPy or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using NumPy since Python itself doesn't have multidimensional arrays.

The easy way to do this is using a ["flat"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) view of the array:

```
myarray.flat[-1] = 1
```